# text-align doesn't work and alternative to centering text doesn't look the way I want it to

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to work with the grid system in bootstrap (Which I don't use a lot).
But when I add text to it it doesn't work like I want it to work.

This is the complete code with the columns:

```
 <div id="villas">
    <div class="villas-inner">
        <div class="villa-main-text">
            <strong>The</strong> Villa's
        </div>
        <div class="villa-boxes">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="villa-box">
                        <div class="more-info-villa">
                            <div class="arrow">
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="assets/img/villa1.png" alt="Villa 1">
                        <div class="villa-info">
                            <strong>Villa test</strong><br>
                            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sed ante tempor, pulvinar metus ut, euismod velit. Fusce a ligula.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="villa-box">
                        <div class="more-info-villa">
                            <div class="arrow">
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="assets/img/villa1.png" alt="Villa 1">
                        <div class="villa-info">
                            <strong>Villa test</strong><br>
                            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sed ante tempor, pulvinar metus ut, euismod velit. Fusce a ligula.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="villa-box">
                        <div class="more-info-villa">
                            <div class="arrow">
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="assets/img/villa1.png" alt="Villa 1">
                        <div class="villa-info">
                            <strong>Villa test</strong><br>
                            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sed ante tempor, pulvinar metus ut, euismod velit. Fusce a ligula.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css that I use for the text in villa-info:

```
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
padding-top: 25px;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

**When I use text-align: center; instead of all that it just aligns my text to the left.**

And the result that it creates is: [image: Villa]

Does someone know how I can fix this? It has been bothering for a long time, does it have something to do with the grid system or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create a minimal example? with the code you provided it's hard to tell http://www.bootply.com/PrJsL03awI

Comment: What do you mean by example? @ZimSystem

Comment: There's no reason to be using `position:absolute` here.

Comment: When I remove position: absolute; it aligns it to the left

Comment: @RikNijdeken http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

**use it in css**

```
.image{
border:2px solid red;
width: 50%;
}
```

**and the html code is**

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="img_1212.jpg" alt="" width="304" height="228">
  <figcaption>Fig.1 - A view of the pulpit rock in NorwayA view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
</div>
```